# VPN Between OpenStack and AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, openstack, openstack-neutron

I have an OpenStack server with Vms.  I have a number of instances in AWS.  The VMs in both cases need to see each other.

I could setup Tinc or OpenVPN on VMs but this seems prone to failure.

I've read about Neutron/VPNaaS, but the documents I've read assume 'multiple OpenStack hosts' and don't talk about connecting to an AWS VPN Gateway.

Is there documentation for 'VPNaaS - AWS'?  Another solution I'm not seeing?